# Нужна заглавная буква в резолюции на закрытие

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Имеется [закрытый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554517/). Текст резолюции начинается со строчной буквы:

> [image: Плашка]

Как мне кажется, первая буква должна быть прописной. Ну и точка в конце не помешает.

Comment: На SO не любят эти правила. Это везде, от ссылки "добавить комментарий" до футера.

Comment: Как мне кажется, тут очень важно оценить масштаб проблемы: сколько строк по всему сайту необходимо будет изменить? Какие именно? В каких местах? Одной строкой тут не отделаешься. Для уточнения правил языка, задал вопрос на сайте [Русский язык](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426369/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил заглавную букву и точку в конце предложения. Затронуты следующие случаи:

- Перенесён с ...
- Перенесён на ...
- Объединён ...
- Объявлен требующим правки ...
- Заблокирован ...
- Отмечен как дубликат ...
- Защищён ...
- Удалён ...
- Закрыт ...
- Поднят на главную страницу ...

Будет доступно на сайте после подкачки transifex и пересборки движка (>2017.8.29.26875).

Если что-то забыл, просьба указать в комментариях.