# Автоматическое описание правки

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

Если сделать правку сообщения и не заполнять поле "Описание", то в описание попадает автоматически сгенерированный список выполненных действий.

Но как мне кажется выглядит этот список несколько несогласованно. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/559738/revisions):

> в текст добавлено 12 символов; изменённые метки; изменённый заголовок

Для согласованности должно быть хотя бы так:

> в текст добавлено 12 символов; изменены метки; изменён заголовок

Ну и [по-прежнему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3534/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) я считаю, что хорошо бы видеть в начале заглавную букву и точку в конце.

Comment: Поправил строки (за исключением заглавны букв), в ближайшее время будут доступны на сайте! Заглавные буквы – общая задача, не относящаяся к опечаткам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я так понимаю, изменения надо будет уже для новых ситуаций проверять, т.к. в старых текст сохранится как есть. Я прав?

Comment: Да, совершено верно!